# Através de um tuplo de 2 listas fazer um grafico

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu tenho 1 tuplo com 2 listas listas como por exemplo  as seguintes , em que a primeira contem datas no formata AAAAMMDD e a segunda contem o numero de vezes que um crime aconteceu nesse dia.

```
tuplo= (['20160130', '20160230', '20160330', '20160430', '20160530', '20160730'] [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
```

O que eu pretendo fazer é uma função que mostre um grafico com o numero de crimes que ocorreu em cada dia, sendo que as abcissas correspondem aos anos e as ordenadas ao numero de crimes.

```
def fazer_grafico(tuplo):

    x = list()
    for anos in tuplo[0]:
        x.append(anos[:4])
     # x é uma lista só com os anos

    x_tmp = range(0, len(x), len(x)/len(set(x)))
    y= grafico[1]


    pylab.plot(range(len(x)), y)
    x= sorted(set(x))
    x.append(" ")
    pylab.xticks(x_tmp,sorted(set(y)))
```

A função está a fazer o grafico correto no entanto faz só fazer uma coisa que é a minha duvida, o que é que eu posso fazer e depois alterar no meu codigo para que as abcissas neste caso o x , tenha em conta os anos com 365 e 366 dias , porque supostamente com 365 a largura do eixo vai ser menor e com 366 vai ser maior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de criar o x_tmp assim:

```
x_tmp = range(0, len(x), len(x)/len(set(x)))
```

Crie conforme o ano em questão. Sabe que se o ano for bissexto é divisível por 4, caso contrário não é, por exemplo:

```
x_tmp = [0]
Para cada ano de sorted(set(x)):
    Se ano bissexto:
        adicionar 366 à ultima entrada de x_tmp e fazer append a x_tmp
    Caso contrário:
        adicionar 365 à ultima entrada de x_tmp e fazer append a x_tmp
```

Penso que assim terá a lsita com o número de dias que passaram ao ano em questao.